# Tomcat not able to read context path in application.Properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat8, application.properties

In Tomcat 8.5.45  -. war file it as web-inf/classes folder which have application.properties(having server context path defined) , but when we run startup.bat -> not able to read application.properties

Comment: In the title of your question you have wrong casing in the filename for ```application.Properties```. Can you please check the casing in your code?

Comment: Hi , in my code i have "application.properties" only  and Spring boot version is 2.3.5.Release

Comment: So you are doing a WAR deployment?

Comment: Yes,simon ,doing war deployment

Comment: All `server` properties are only used when using an embedded container. When deploying a war those have no use. Spring (boot) cannot control an externally managed servlet container.

Comment: is their any possible way to configure those propertiets in external tomcat